# Laravel Homestead errors

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm getting the following errors when I start up Laravel's Homestead. I've never had issues running it before. Today, I had to upgrade Vagrant and Virtual Box. Below is the complete output, but I'll highlight the errors:

```
Bobs-MacBook-Air:Applications bob$ homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
default: Adapter 1: nat
default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
default: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few    minutes...
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: 
default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
 default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
default: 
default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
default: /vagrant => /Users/bob/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
default: /home/vagrant/Code => /Users/bob/Code
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: inline script
==> default: ssh-rsa     AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDB38DDrXR6I0zGeWaKFD3FPkDSVuWIOz799ZtEH3jI8cqAvi3yDcFHLD1hCEyJbdoB5nrXI7TqkuGNdHpqo3auliwUshlg1kHahW4//hsWufv4W33vUDeh8UwOpAWKYc6JrSR5+/LCFomwdr2E7kq1wQKG0O4bcvXyZ/gn+umAf9YYiLA7XJViZUc7OOyNhNVRIXSL6NpH9hhsv9NHmB6Xe+hGiB2ctGD00xeh9GxEvORtMQhwjiVN9BiOaAJAM+kH23hS8j5mkxQBgVGANTa5IREVeEOfI+zsT73HFuEU7I8sXZrdl6XJwmdW8zUkzvMrxwucdTDYQkcAcYP/MsXJ bob@Bobs-MacBook-Air.local
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running:     /var/folders/cr/44dtbc853jq9lyc2mwhg87m80000gn/T/vagrant-shell20170119-5395-doo0yi.sh
 ==> default: Failed to restart php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service not found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

1. default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
   default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
2. ==> default: Failed to restart php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service not found.

How can I fix these errors so Homestead runs like normal? I'm using OSX.